# Conditional UPDATE for non-related tables in SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update `historicTable` (8k records containing employee data) when 2 IDs match (one company id and the other area id) with the `tempTable`, which is a temporary table with the data I want to update (`SUBG_ROT`), else (the column stays empty), it should copy data from `colx` to `coly` from the same historic table. I was thinking of a JOIN/INNER JOIN but I can't get the structure at all, so I did a stored procedure with a conditional update, but I can't figure out how to call the temporary table. Any hints on the logic/code are appreciated, I'm starting on SQL Server so I'm kinda clueless.

In my mind the code should do:

```
Update historicTable set SUBG when h.id1 = t.id1 and h.id2 = t.id2 then h.SUBG = t.SUBG else h.id1 = h.SUBG
```

And this is the code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateHistoric
AS
UPDATE dbo.historicTable 
    SET SUBG_ROT = CASE
                    WHEN id1 = temptable.id1 AND id2 = temptable.id2 
                        THEN SUBG_ROT = temptable.SUBG_ROT
                        ELSE SUBG_ROT = AREA
                        END
GO
```

Comment: Look at the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: AREA belongs to which table?

Comment: @PSK To the same historic table, if there is no id match (tempTable gets updated often) it should copy area, wich will work for future data updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `OUTER APPLY` like follownig.

```
UPDATE t 
SET    t.subg_rot = CASE 
                    WHEN o.subg_rot IS NOT NULL THEN o.subg_rot 
                    WHEN t.subg_rot IS null then t.area 
                    ELSE t.subg_rot
                  END 
FROM   dbo.historictable t 
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 subg_rot 
                    FROM   temptable t2 
                    WHERE  t1.id1 = t2.id1 
                           AND t1.id2 = t2.id2)o
```

Note: Same thing is also possible using `LEFT JOIN` or  sub queries.

Comment: It works splendid, but where data already exist on the `historicTable` it overrides AREA with SUBG (when I don't need it on existing records), how can I exclude the update on those record?. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I have updated the answer and I feel it should work. Please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Thank you! But the case actually worked like this : `WHEN t.SUBG IS NOT NULL THEN t.SUBG 
     WHEN t.SUBG IS NULL THEN t.AREA
     ELSE t.SUBG` Marking your answer as correct. Thanks again!